# Python function returns None, unclear why

Tags: python

I am pretty new to python and am hitting an issue I cannot explain. I have tried searching through the forum answers here, but what I am finding does not match up with my situation. It feels like I am missing something pretty basic, but I'm not seeing it (obviously...)

This code runs the way I expect:

```
import string

mults = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,15,16,19,21,22,24]

def factor_exp(lst):
    if lst[-1] == 1:
        lst.pop()
        return lst+[1]
    if lst[-1] == 2:
        lst.pop()
        return lst+[1,1]
    else:
        return "Should never get here"

print factor_exp([1])
print factor_exp([2])
print factor_exp([1,2])
```

This returns:

```
>>> 
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 1, 1]
```

Which is what I want.

I thought using append and extend on the list inside the function would work also. One "append" added near the bottom of the code.

```
import string

mults = [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,15,16,19,21,22,24]

def factor_exp(lst):
    if lst[-1] == 1:
        lst.pop()
        return lst+[1]
    if lst[-1] == 2:
        lst.pop()
        return lst.append([1,1])
    else:
        return "Should never get here"


print factor_exp([1])
print factor_exp([2])
print factor_exp([1,2])
```

But this returns:

```
>>> 
[1]
None
None
```

Why are the "None's" appearing? Thanks in advance for any help or insights.

Comment: Look at this documentation: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html... If it doesnt specifically say that it returns something then you can assume that it returns None.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't study your code, but I'd say that it's for this line:

```
return lst.append([1,1])
```

`list.append()` always returns `None`.

So `lst.append([1,1])` will append `[1,1]` to `lst` and return `None`.

Comment: I agree, this is a common mistake, I used to think that `list.append` would return the appended item too.